# mysql - if value = 0 shorten where statement

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I wonder if it's possible to shorten query depending on some variable value in elegant way.

For example: I have value named `$var = 0` and I would like to send a query that looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, quantity FROM products WHERE quantity > 100";
```

But whan the $var != 1 I'd like to send a query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, quantity FROM products WHERE quantity > 100 AND id = '$var'";
```

So depending on value of $var I want to execute one of queries. They differ only with last expression. 
I found two possible solutions but they are not elegant and I dont like them at all.

One is made in php:

```
if ( $var == 0 ) {
  $query_without_second_expression
} else {
  $query_with_second_expression
}
```

Second is made in mysql:

```
SELECT WHEN '$var' <> 0 THEN id, name, quantity 
FROM products WHERE quantity > 100 AND id = '$var' ELSE id, name, quantity 
FROM products WHERE quantity > 100 END
```

but i dont like it - each idea doubles queries in some whay. Can I do something like this?

```
SELECT id, name, quantity 
FROM products WHERE quantity > 100 
CASE WHEN $var <> 0 THEN AND id = '$var'
```

It's much shorter, and adds part of query if needed. Of course real query is much more complicated and shorter statement would be really expected. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand well..

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, quantity FROM products WHERE quantity > 100";
if ( $var != 0 ) {
  $query .= " AND id = '$var'";
}
```

do you like it?

Comment: I was working on this, but please remove the `AND id = $var` part from the original `$query`

Comment: i hoped that i can make it all in mysql, not in php. But i'm sure your example will work and i am going to use it. thank you. +1 from me

Comment: @Kalreg It's better to do this in PHP anyway - it can be done in just SQL, but it would likely be slower - you have to check the condition for every row, which is wasted processing when the condition always returns true.

Answer (score 2):

You could so something like this on the SQL side:

```
"SELECT id, name, quantity FROM products WHERE quantity > 100 AND (id = '$var' OR '$var' = 0)
```

But performance could be impacted. I would suggest building the appropriate query on the PHP side.

Comment: i like your example most but it wont work in my project. if the $var = 0 i still have an expression that selects products with id = 0. I dont want it - i want if var = 0 the print all products, and if var > 0 only with id = var

Comment: Then it should work. The key part is (id = '$var' OR '$var' = 0). This will return true if id = '$var' or if '$var' = 0. By setting $var to 0, it should return everything.

Answer (score 1):

If they only differ in additional where-statements, I would probably still stay in PHP and do the following:

```
$conditions = array();
$conditions[] = "(quantity > 100)"

if ($var == 0)
  $conditions[] = "(id = '$var')";

if (some-other-expression)
  $conditions[] = "(myfield = 'foo' OR myfield = 'bar')";

$sql = "
  SElECT id, name, quantity
  FROM products
  WHERE
";
$sql .= $conditions.join(" AND ");
```

/ Carsten

Answer (score 1):

I'm no PHP developer (it is PHP, right?), but wouldn't it be easiest to build your query from a concatenated string?

Pseudo-code:

```
$my_query = "SELECT id, name, quantity FROM products WHERE quantity > 100"

if ($var != 1)
   $my_query = $my_query + " AND id = '$var'";
end if;

/*go ahead with your query*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
SELECT id, name, quantity 
FROM products 
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND ( $q   IS NULL OR quantity > $q)
       AND ( $var IS NULL OR id = $var)
```

If you want only the first condition to run then pass `$q = 100` and `$var = NULL`, therefore the second condition will be ignored. And for the second query pass the `$q = 100` and `$var = id value` and you will got the your second query.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a ternary for this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, quantity FROM products WHERE quantity > 100" . ( $var != 0 ? " AND id = '$var'" : '' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Oracle guy, but could you use the `IF()` function in your constraints, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, name, quantity
  FROM products
 WHERE quantity > 100
   AND id = IF('$var'=0,'%','$var');
```

The '%' is a wildcard that would match anything, effectively ignoring the 2nd expression.

Answer (score 1):

So if you are using the

> If or the CASE

Why don't you use them in your sql query.
It would be some like

```
if ( $var == 0 ) {
$query_without_second_expression
}
else 
{
 $query_with_second_expression
}
```

But in you sql query.

```
DECLARE @var int
if(@var=1)
BEGIN
    query 1
END

else 
BEGIN
     query 2
end
```

I guess this will solve your problem.
But as a personal advice try to make one query. Even with the variable. We don't believe in changing standard query depending on the conditions.

Still your wish and your desire

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

For this particular problem, go with Paper-bat's simple condition append snippet.

However, if you have entirely different where statements, consider appending the appropriate where statement to the query once you know what you want. For instance,

```
$query = "SELECT id, name, quantity FROM products ";
if ( $var == 0 ) {
  $query .= "quantity > 100";
} elseif {
  $query .= "quantity > 120 AND id = '$var'";
} elseif {
...
}
...
```

It all depends on your needs, but neither this or Paper-bat's solutions duplicate query code.